# Send Email with Camel an Java. ISSUE STARTTLS error

Tags: java, apache, smtp, apache-camel

I know this question has been asked before, but I tried several sollutions and the problem still persists, so and help would be much appreciated.

I am trying to configure to send email throu gmail and smtp. Below is our camel configuration:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <camel:route id="gmailRoute">
        <camel:from uri="direct://gmail" />
        <camel:to
            uri="smtp://p****is@gmail.com?host=smtp.gmail.com&amp;port=587&amp;from=p****is@gmail.comi&amp;password=gl******" />
    </camel:route>
```

On the init method of our service implementation we have the following:

```
   log.info("Initializing Email Service");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    Authenticator auth = null;
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        auth = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("******akis@gmail.com", "gl*****s");
            }
        };
    Session t = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

    template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
```

and on the sendmail method we have:

```
  @Override
public void sendEmail(String from, String[] to, String[] cc, String[] bcc, String subject, String body)
{
String endpoint = "direct://gmail";
    String toString = null;
    String ccString = null;
    String bccString = null;
    Map<String, Object> headers = null;

    toString = convertStringArrayToCSV(to);
    ccString = convertStringArrayToCSV(cc);
    bccString = convertStringArrayToCSV(bcc);

    headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    headers.put("Subject", subject);
    if (toString != null)
    {
        headers.put("To", toString);
    }

    if (ccString != null)
    {
        headers.put("CC", ccString);
    }

    if (bccString != null)
    {
        headers.put("BCC", bccString);
    }

    template.sendBodyAndHeaders(endpoint, body, headers);

}
```

the problem is that when we try to send an email using the sendmail method we get the following error:

> caught: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For Gmail, this seems to be the way to go:

```
smtp://smtp.gmail.com?port=587&username=USERNAME@gmail.com&password=PASSOWRD&mail.smtp.auth=true&mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

This last parameter is the one your error message was complaining about. Basically, all the custom SMTP params you have in the Java code you listed, also need to be in Camel endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

To send to Gmail from Camel you require the following:-

1. Gmail SMTP certificate in a KeyStore (i.e. OpenSSL or a Python script together with the Java KeyTool)
2. Either allow less secure apps (not desirable)
3. Or setup 2-step authentication with an App Password for your route
4. SSLContextParameters configured

You could use the following instructions listed to achieve these steps:-
https://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/sending-email-to-gmail-in-apache-camel/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using TLS security to send your email but using the non-secure version of the Mail component. Can you try changing smtp to smtps?

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <camel:route id="gmailRoute">
    <camel:from uri="direct://gmail" />
    <camel:to uri="smtps://p****is@gmail.com?host=smtp.gmail.com&amp;port=587&amp;from=p****is@gmail.comi&amp;password=gl******" />
  </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: In this case, I just get javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?